# Sort a list of objects according to a property in another list

Tags: python, sorting

My data consists of objects with some property (`pk`):

```
obj0.pk = 'aa'
obj1.pk = 33
ojb2.pk = 'm0'
```

I have a bunch of unordered objects:

```
data = [obj0, obj1, obj2]
```

And I have the list of pks which specify how to order the objects:

```
pks = [33, 'aa', 'm0']
```

Now I call a function to order the data:

```
output = sort_data_by_pk(data, pks)
```

Expected output:

```
[obj1, obj0, obj2]
```

How can we implement `sort_data_by_pk` in python?

### EDIT

My initial implementation is:

```
def sort_data_by_pk(data, pks):
    lookup = {instance.pk: instance for instance in data}
    return [lookup[pk] for pk in pks]
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Because `[33, 'aa', 'm0']` is only natively sortable in 2.7 and below. Python 3 refuses to compare strs against ints unless you take pains to specify how that should be done.

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood the purpose of `pks`. If that list is defining a total ordering, then there's no direct comparison between elements.

Comment: I would appreciate if downvoters explain their reasons ...

Comment: @volingas I did not downvote but usually people downvote whenever a question is posted without the OP showing some effort in attempting an implementation. Your edit now shows that you did make a good (actually, great) attempt in implementation, so +1 to you.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `index` method as a key function unnecessarily makes the solution *O(n^2 log n)*  rather than *O(n log n)* in average time complexity.

Instead, you can build a dict that maps the items in `data` to their indices, so that you can use the dict to map the objects' `pk` attribute as a key function for sort order:

```
order = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(pks)}
output = sorted(data, key=lambda o: order[o.pk])
```

Comment: That was my initial implementation, but creating an extra dict looked a bit clunky

Comment: If the size of your `data` is large then the *O(1)* efficiency in lookup that the extra dict brings is well worth the extra line of code.

Comment: Actually, I realize that my implementation is different. I have added it to my question. Do you see any advantage / disadvantage compared to your implementation?

Comment: Yes, your implementation is much better since it takes only *O(n)* in time complexity. I got distracted by the `sorted` function used by the other answers that I forgot that in your case it can simply be done with a reversed index lookup.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep mine then.

Answer (score 2):

You could `sort` `data` based on the `index` in the `pks` like,

```
>>> pks = [33, 'aa', 'm0']
>>> data = [ob0, ob1, ob2]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda x: pks.index(x.pk))
[<__main__.Obj object at 0x7f03851cc290>, <__main__.Obj object at 0x7f03851cc250>, <__main__.Obj object at 0x7f03851cc2d0>]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `sorted` with a lambda that gets the index of the primary key in `pks`.

```
sorted_data = sorted(data, lambda d: pks.index(d.pk))
```

Answer (score 2):

If your lists are big, you might want to create a dict first, to avoid multiple calls of "index" on the list.

```
pks = [33, 'aa', 'm0']
data = [ob0, ob1, ob2]
d = { obj.pk: obj for obj in data } #lookup table for pks
sorted_list = [ d[pk] for pk in pks ] #create a new list out of list "pks" where pk is replaced by the value in the lookup table
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my original implementation, which I have added to the question